# Issue with events in Ionic 3

Tags: angular, events, ionic3

I try use the events library like a session option so i can keep the id user,etc
It work fine when I do the login process and go to home or second page, but when i want to go to thir page , i miss the value , i would like to know if this issue is common or i need update something on my code

On the three pages:

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';
```

and into main class:

constructor( public events: Events,....

---

In 1 page:

login function , process ok:

```
 this.navCtrl.push('PanelPage').then(() => {
      this.events.publish('usuario', usuario['Nombre']);
      this.events.publish('usuario_id', usuario['Id']);
      this.events.publish('usuario_rol', usuario['Roles']);
      //console.log('Published');
    });
```

---

2 page (works fine)

```
constructor(  public events: Events,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {

  this.events.subscribe('usuario', (user) => {
      console.log('user name:', user)


  });
  this.events.subscribe('usuario_id', (user_id) => {
    console.log('id de user name:', user_id)


  });
  this.events.subscribe('usuario_rol', (user_rol) => {
    console.log('rol de user en panel:', user_rol)
    this.usuario_rol = user_rol;
```

### });

3 page (I cant see the events):

```
 constructor( public cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public events: Events, private toastCtrl: ToastController, public plt: Platform,public sqlite: SQLite, public formBuilder: FormBuilder,  private sqliteService:SqLiteProvider)
```

{

```
this.events.subscribe('usuario_rol', (user_rol: any) => {
  console.log('Rol en preventa:', user_rol);
  this.usuario_rol = user_rol;

});
```

---

I've tried in constructor,   ionViewWillEnter(), etc but nothing happens...

Please, thanks in advance for some help or tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when the third page is created, the event has already been published and only affects the already subscribed elements. You should either publish it again on the second page, or a better solution would be to store this info in a separate/global service and access this info on the constructor or ionViewWillEnter method.

**Edit**

You have two options:

1) Use Local Storage
2) Use a provider to store variables

**1) Use Local Storage:**
Install [Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/storage) from Ionic Native

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic-native/storage';

constructor(private storage: Storage){}    

this.navCtrl.push('PanelPage').then(() => {
  this.storage.set('usuario', usuario['Nombre']);
  this.storage.set('usuario_id', usuario['Id']);
  this.storage.set('usuario_rol', usuario['Roles']);
});
```

And on page two and three:

```
import { Storage } from '@ionic-native/storage';

constructor(private storage: Storage){}  

ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.usuario_rol = await this.storage.get('usario_rol');
}
```

**2) Use a provider to store variables**

`ionic g provider global`

providers/global/global.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalProvider {

  usuario: any;
  usuario_id: any;
  usuario_rol: any;

  constructor() {}
}
```

On first page:

```
import { GlobalProvider } from '../../providers/global/global';

constructor(private global: GlobalProvider){}

this.navCtrl.push('PanelPage').then(() => {
  this.global.usuario = usuario['Nombre'];
  this.global.usuario_id = usuario['Id'];
  this.global.usuario_rol = usuario['Roles'];
});
```

Pages two and three:

```
import { GlobalProvider } from '../../providers/global/global';

constructor(private global: GlobalProvider){}

ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.usuario_rol = this.global.usuario_rol
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chester, sorry, do you have some link or sample about the second option? (im newbie with ionic 3 and im not sure how implement these services) thanks in advance for your help

Comment: You're a genius, but beyond it, a great professional and a bettter person. Finally, I try the second option (Im not sure if storage is local only on browsers and i need android support) and it worked great.  Is was very clear, a great example, the type of sample that let me learn more .Thanks!!

Comment: Glad it helped, the storage options works both on web and mobile(android and ios)